# Conditional border creation for excel based on length of text

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Okay so I've spent some time digging through stack overflow other various websites, I'm not even sure this is possible but here's the example.

I have an excel sheet with quite a bit of information, in column A there are various types of information however I specifically only want the cells that have #####-###.

The issue is that the other users will sometimes replace the last 3 digits with question marks and similarly, when adding the dash it doesn't treat it as a number it's considered general format...

Like I said I maybe have the number 60613-555, then right below it part numbers/names etc, so I only want that cell with the project number to have the top line border...

Comment: use: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("????-???",A1))` as the formula.

Comment: Thank you for the speedy reply, is there a way to make it extend the entire row? border, with VBA code maybe instead of conditional formatting?
EDIT: For some reason it works but its putting the border below, if I change the format parameters to full outline it outlines the cell below the number 92000-111

Comment: That is just making the `applies to` input include the entirety of the range you want to apply the rule.  also make the column absolute if you only want to look at column A for the criteria: `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("????-???",$A1))`

Comment: To your edit, then your first reference is not to the full column.  using `$A1` you need to start the `Applies to:` in the first row.  If your `Applies to:` starts in row 2 ie: `$A$2:$N$1000` then you need to change the `$A1` to `$A2` the row in the formula must refer to the first row in the `Applies to:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this as the rule:

```
=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("????-???",$A1))
```

And apply it to the columns desired:

[image]

Comment: Awesome yeah that is working but like I mentioned in my edit, For some reason it works but its putting the border below, if I change the format parameters to full outline it outlines the cell below the number 92000-111 -not exactly my initial question but thoughts as to why it is apply it to cells below instead?

Comment: See my comment above.  Your formula cell reference and the `Applies to:` are out of sync.